# Jones formalism for calculating quarter waveplate angle for circular polarized light

Tags: visible-light, laser, optics

I am planning to change the polarization of a vertically linear polarized laser to circular polarized light with the help of a quarter waveplate.

I know the final result: I have to rotate the fast axis of the waveplate 45° to the incident polarization axis in order to achieve left handed circular polarized light. A rotation of -45° results in right handed polarization.

My task is know to use the Jones formalism to calculate this result.
Vertically linear polarized light can be written in Jones matrices as

\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}

right handed circular polarized light can be written in Jones matrices as

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -i\end{pmatrix}$$

left handed circular polarized light can be written in Jones matrices as

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ i\end{pmatrix}$$

Now I don't know how to proceed from here. Has anyone a good advise for me?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- The [Jones matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus#Jones_matrices) for e.g. right circular polarized light is: $$\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & i \\ -i & -1
  \end{pmatrix}$$ To see this try applying this matrix to your linearly polarized Jones vector. It will give a right circularly polarized Jones vector.
- The Jones matrix for a [quarter wave plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus#Phase_retarders) is:$$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi/2}
  \end{pmatrix}$$
  You can see this e.g. by applying it to the vectors $\begin{pmatrix}
  1  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
  0  \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ separately and observing the phase difference that is introduced between the two.
- Furthermore you can always build in [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions), which corresponds to physically rotating e.g. your quarter waveplate relative to the incoming polarization.

Now you can try to build the required matrix (see first point above) from a quarter waveplate and rotations, which will solve the problem.